Is Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics explanation that the oscillation period between $|S\rangle$ and $|A\rangle$ is infinite wrong?
[Errors that persist in the 3rd edition of Sakurai's textbook?]
The content dealing with the symmetry double-well potential contains an error in the coefficient of $|A\rangle$ in $|R,\,t\rangle$, where the sign of the exponent is incorrect. I checked previous editions, and this error was not present in the revised edition, but it has persisted through the 2nd and 3rd editions.
Moreover, when the double-well potential becomes infinite, the eigenstates become degenerate, and the oscillation period between $|R\rangle$ and $|L\rangle$ should be infinite. However, the textbook states that the oscillation period between $|S\rangle$ and $|A\rangle$ is infinite, which seems like a mistake.
Is my thought correct that the explanation is wrong?


Are you just saying that in Equation (4.78) it should be $e^{-iE_At/\hslash}$ and then $e^{-i(E_A-E_S)t/\hslash}$? Yes to that, and yes to your noting that it should be $\left|R\right>$ and $\left|L\right>$ oscillation rather than $\left|S\right>$ and $\left|A\right>$ oscillation.

To naturallyinconsistent : Thank you for your response. It has been very helpful in my studies.
